# How can I see what jobs have been queued with resque-scheduler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque, resque-scheduler

If I enqueue a job using `Resque.enqueue` I can open up a snazzy interface at `localhost:(whatever)/resque` and see my queued jobs. But if I schedule a job using the `resque-scheduler` gem (e.g. by using `Resque.enqueue_at(10.minutes.from_now, MyJob)`), it doesn't appear in that interface - all I can do is wait 10 minutes and see if `MyJob` gets executed!

Is there no way I can see what jobs have been queued, programmatically or otherwise? Do I have to go digging around in Redis?

Comment: did you tried resque-web additions described in https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler#user-content-resque-web-additions ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that when properly configured your Resque web interface should have two new tabs: "Schedule" and "Delayed". That's where you can see them.

for more information: https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler#user-content-resque-web-additionsstack